# Keep map annotation selected while clustering / declustering

Tags: ios, mapkit, selection, mkannotation

I'm using iOS 11's `clusterIdentifier` to cluster annotations on an `MKMapView` together when the user zooms out and they would otherwise overlap. It works great.

However, when I select an annotation on the map like this

```
mapView.selectAnnotation(closestShopAnnotation, animated: true)
```

while the corresponding annotation view is currently hidden by a cluster annotation view, nothing happens, just as the method's documentation says:

> If the specified annotation is not onscreen, and therefore does not have an associated annotation view, this method has no effect.

However, I want that particular annotation to be selected as soon as the user zooms in and the corresponding annotation view becomes visible to the user as a result of declustering.

**Is there a way to keep the selection state of an `MKAnnotationView` instance persistent** throughout several times of clustering & declustering (by zooming in and out)?

Comment: You should then select the annotation under which your annotation is clustered.